# How do I find latest item for timeseries data?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, time-series, data-analysis

For example, there are timeseries data like root partition utilization. The data structure is like below:

```
name: root_disk_utilizatoin
ip: 1.1.1.1
timestamp: 1234567890
value: 0.5
```

We have millions of servers reporting this data every few minutes. **My expection is to find latest data for each server.**

The first idea is to store these timeseries data in some storage like elasticsearc or tsdb(influxdb/opentsdb). Then query the storage to get result. But I worry about the **performance**. No mater what storage I chose, they must do below two steps to archieve the result.

1. group data by ip
2. sort data by timestamp and return the latest one

I guess this will be a very expensive process(cost a lot of time).

So I guess this may not be a good idea.

- Do you have similar requirements and how do you solve it?
- Will it be a problem for timeseries db like influxdb?

Comment: You must first specify the rate of data input? then with input rate and type of query, decide what DB can handle your tasks. maybe apache cassandra is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use a combination of [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation) with [max
> aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html)

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "root_disk_utilizatoin",
  "ip": "1.1.1.2",
  "timestamp": 1234567891,
  "value": 0.5
}
{
  "name": "root_disk_utilizatoin",
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "timestamp": 1234567890,
  "value": 0.5
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ip.keyword",
        "order": {
          "latestOrder": "desc"
        },
        "size":1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latestOrder": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "unique_id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 1,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1.1.1.2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.234567891E9
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: The OP said there were "millions of servers reporting every few minutes"... A terms aggregation with millions of buckets is costly to build

Comment: Yes @Val it will be a costly solution, but OP also want to `group data by ip`, and as far as I know it can be achieved by terms aggregation only. Is there any other way to achieve that ?

Comment: In this case, I would probably leverage the `composite` aggregation (with `terms` source) instead, that way the OP can efficiently paginate the results...

Comment: he didnt decided what database he want to use. he dont have any clue that mysql is out of the game when talking about big data. :))

Comment: @Kramer Li did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)